# Accessing my VMware Ubuntu client through Wi-Fi network

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, vmware

I am trying to connect to my client VM through my home network but am not able to do it. Hopefully I am able to explain my situation - it is way out of my field. :/ The client runs Ember server.

Through the Virtual Network Editor and NAT settings, I am able to expose the client's Ember port (4200) to the shame port of my Host. So hitting localhost:4200 shows the ember application.

My host (Windows 10) is ethernet-connected to the router and has an ip 192.168.1.110 which I can access through the Wi-Fi network. What I am trying to achieve is hitting 192.168.1.110:4200 through the Wi-Fi network and exposing the Ember application.

I am not sure if what I want to achieve has to do with my router's forwarding, with VMWare settings, or anything else. :/

Comment: VMWare settings. You need to set it so your VM has a distinct IP address.

Comment: Can you please elaborate a bit more?

Comment: Not really because I don't use VMWare and I don't known the exact configurations. That said, you need to setup the network connection (at VMWare) in a way that your VM has its own IP address, different from the host's IP. Perhaps try bridged instead?

Comment: You mean a different ip in the local home network? aka 192.168.1.XXX ?

Comment: Of course. Where else?